# TYPO3: Search in tt_content and tt_news

Tags: typo3

Im looking to build a search box for my website that looks for content in tt_content as well as in tt_news.

Could anyone recommend me an TYPO3 extension maybe to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try indexed search? http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/doc_indexed_search/4.2.1/view/

Comment: The documentation is quite outdated, but Ill give it a whirl. Thanks!

Comment: Pages are only indexed once they have been cached in the front end or you will need to install the crawler extension for it to crawl the pagetree. http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/crawler

Comment: Mybee outdated Docs, but indexed search is still the way to go for TYPO3 V 6.2